# Set-AzContext: Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription

Tags: azure, powershell

[image: Set-AzContext: Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.]

I am trying to swap over to a different subscription within my Azure Account. The subscription is correct and the command itself seems to be correct but I am getting the error in the screenshot. Any suggestions..?

Comment: I avoid issues like that by doing `Get-AzContext -ListAvailable | Where{$_.Name -match 'MySub1'} | Set-AzContext` and then just fill in the name of the subscription or something. You can just run `Get-AzContext -ListAvailable` to see what subscriptions are available to you.

Comment: Thanks @TheMadTechnician this worked for me. I was getting the subscription name as a string from .yml pipeline.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician you should put your comment as an answer. It's by far the best solution to this issue in this SO post

Answer (score 3):

I avoid issues like that by listing all of your subscriptions you have access to, filter those for the one you want, and set that as your active context.

```
Get-AzContext -ListAvailable | Where{$_.Name -match 'MySub1'} | Set-AzContext
```

You just need to fill in the name of the subscription or something. You can also run `Get-AzContext -ListAvailable` to see what subscriptions are available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you logged in with the correct AAD tenant which the subscription locates in, just pass the tenant id to the command.

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription <subscription-id> -Tenant <tenant-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

After receiving this error I ran

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
```

Logged in to the login screen that appeared and it started working